# Massif visualizer can't display text in legend

Tags: valgrind, massif

I already generate a massif output file use command

```
valgrind --tool=massif --time-unit=ms  ./prog
```

and then open this output file through massif visualizer.

Most of them work well, but the text in label can't display properly(empty square)

[image]

Are there any suggestion for me to let text show up properly ? Thanks!

Following output is another method to draw graph: `$ ms_print massif.out.16245`

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Command:            ./prog
Massif arguments:   --time-unit=B --stacks=yes
ms_print arguments: massif.out.16245
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------


    KB
20.13^                                                             #          
    |                                                             #          
    |                                                             #:         
    |                                                             #:         
    |                                                           @@#:         
    |                                                           @ #:         
    |                                                           @ #::        
    |                                                           @ #::        
    |                                                          @@ #:::       
    |                                                          @@ #:::  :    
    |                                                         @@@ #:::::::@::
    |                                                         @@@ #:::::::@::
    |                                                        @@@@ #:::::::@::
    |                                                        @@@@ #:::::::@::
    |    @@::                                                @@@@ #:::::::@::
    |    @ :                                                :@@@@ #:::::::@::
    |   :@ : :                                              :@@@@ #:::::::@::
    |   :@ : :                                              :@@@@ #:::::::@::
    |   :@ : : :::                                          :@@@@ #:::::::@::
    | : :@ : : :: :@  ::::::::::@::::@::@::::@::::::::::: :::@@@@ #:::::::@::
0 +----------------------------------------------------------------------->KB
    0                                                                   198.5

Number of snapshots: 73
Detailed snapshots: [4, 7, 11, 22, 27, 30, 35, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 57, 59 (peak), 69]

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
n        time(B)         total(B)   useful-heap(B) extra-heap(B)    stacks(B)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0              0                0                0             0            0
1          3,344            1,120                0             0        1,120
2          5,832              824                0             0          824
3         10,016            5,008                0             0        5,008
4         13,800            7,176                0             0        7,176
00.00% (0B) (heap allocation functions) malloc/new/new[], --alloc-fns, etc.

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
n        time(B)         total(B)   useful-heap(B) extra-heap(B)    stacks(B)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
5         18,176            6,400                0             0        6,400
6         22,688            5,008                0             0        5,008
7         26,872              824                0             0          824
00.00% (0B) (heap allocation functions) malloc/new/new[], --alloc-fns, etc.

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
n        time(B)         total(B)   useful-heap(B) extra-heap(B)    stacks(B)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
8         29,760            3,056                0             0        3,056
9         33,240            2,680                0             0        2,680
10         37,624            1,528                0             0        1,528
11         41,144            2,056                0             0        2,056
00.00% (0B) (heap allocation functions) malloc/new/new[], --alloc-fns, etc.

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
n        time(B)         total(B)   useful-heap(B) extra-heap(B)    stacks(B)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
12         44,840              952                0             0          952
13         48,040            1,160                0             0        1,160
14         51,520            1,568                0             0        1,568
15         54,584            1,608                0             0        1,608
16         58,920            1,416                0             0        1,416
17         61,272            1,416                0             0        1,416
18         64,200            1,416                0             0        1,416
19         68,504            1,416                0             0        1,416
20         71,432            1,416                0             0        1,416
21         74,360            1,416                0             0        1,416
22         77,288            1,416                0             0        1,416
00.00% (0B) (heap allocation functions) malloc/new/new[], --alloc-fns, etc.

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
n        time(B)         total(B)   useful-heap(B) extra-heap(B)    stacks(B)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
23         80,216            1,416                0             0        1,416
24         83,144            1,416                0             0        1,416
25         86,072            1,416                0             0        1,416
26         89,000            1,416                0             0        1,416
27         91,912            1,416                0             0        1,416
00.00% (0B) (heap allocation functions) malloc/new/new[], --alloc-fns, etc.

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
n        time(B)         total(B)   useful-heap(B) extra-heap(B)    stacks(B)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
28         94,840            1,416                0             0        1,416
29         98,744            1,416                0             0        1,416
30        101,248            1,312                0             0        1,312
00.00% (0B) (heap allocation functions) malloc/new/new[], --alloc-fns, etc.

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
n        time(B)         total(B)   useful-heap(B) extra-heap(B)    stacks(B)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
31        103,624            1,416                0             0        1,416
32        106,128            1,312                0             0        1,312
33        108,504            1,416                0             0        1,416
34        111,008            1,312                0             0        1,312
35        113,360            1,312                0             0        1,312
00.00% (0B) (heap allocation functions) malloc/new/new[], --alloc-fns, etc.

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
n        time(B)         total(B)   useful-heap(B) extra-heap(B)    stacks(B)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
36        116,912            1,136                0             0        1,136
37        119,216            1,568                0             0        1,568
38        123,832            1,400                0             0        1,400
39        127,616            1,088                0             0        1,088
40        130,080            1,312                0             0        1,312
41        133,584            1,600                0             0        1,600
42        136,096            1,568                0             0        1,568
43        138,392            1,416                0             0        1,416
44        140,928            1,312                0             0        1,312
45        143,352            1,416                0             0        1,416
46        145,888            1,312                0             0        1,312
47        148,176              224                0             0          224
48        151,816            1,432            1,000            16          416
49        156,520            5,496            5,000            80          416
50        158,872            7,528            7,000           112          416
51        158,872            7,528            7,000           112          416
92.99% (7,000B) (heap allocation functions) malloc/new/new[], --alloc-fns, etc.
->92.99% (7,000B) 0x108749: main (in /home/steven/Desktop/linux-design/lab0-c/prog)

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
n        time(B)         total(B)   useful-heap(B) extra-heap(B)    stacks(B)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
52        160,048            8,544            8,000           128          416
93.63% (8,000B) (heap allocation functions) malloc/new/new[], --alloc-fns, etc.
->93.63% (8,000B) 0x108749: main (in /home/steven/Desktop/linux-design/lab0-c/prog)

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
n        time(B)         total(B)   useful-heap(B) extra-heap(B)    stacks(B)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
53        161,224            9,560            9,000           144          416
94.14% (9,000B) (heap allocation functions) malloc/new/new[], --alloc-fns, etc.
->94.14% (9,000B) 0x108749: main (in /home/steven/Desktop/linux-design/lab0-c/prog)

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
n        time(B)         total(B)   useful-heap(B) extra-heap(B)    stacks(B)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
54        162,400           10,576           10,000           160          416
94.55% (10,000B) (heap allocation functions) malloc/new/new[], --alloc-fns, etc.
->94.55% (10,000B) 0x108749: main (in /home/steven/Desktop/linux-design/lab0-c/prog)

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
n        time(B)         total(B)   useful-heap(B) extra-heap(B)    stacks(B)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
55        164,584           12,600           12,000           168          432
95.24% (12,000B) (heap allocation functions) malloc/new/new[], --alloc-fns, etc.
->79.37% (10,000B) 0x108749: main (in /home/steven/Desktop/linux-design/lab0-c/prog)
| 
->15.87% (2,000B) 0x108717: f (in /home/steven/Desktop/linux-design/lab0-c/prog)
->15.87% (2,000B) 0x108765: main (in /home/steven/Desktop/linux-design/lab0-c/prog)

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
n        time(B)         total(B)   useful-heap(B) extra-heap(B)    stacks(B)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
56        168,768           16,624           16,000           176          448
57        168,768           16,624           16,000           176          448
96.25% (16,000B) (heap allocation functions) malloc/new/new[], --alloc-fns, etc.
->60.15% (10,000B) 0x108749: main (in /home/steven/Desktop/linux-design/lab0-c/prog)
| 
->24.06% (4,000B) 0x108706: g (in /home/steven/Desktop/linux-design/lab0-c/prog)
| ->24.06% (4,000B) 0x10871C: f (in /home/steven/Desktop/linux-design/lab0-c/prog)
|   ->24.06% (4,000B) 0x108765: main (in /home/steven/Desktop/linux-design/lab0-c/prog)
|     
->12.03% (2,000B) 0x108717: f (in /home/steven/Desktop/linux-design/lab0-c/prog)
->12.03% (2,000B) 0x108765: main (in /home/steven/Desktop/linux-design/lab0-c/prog)

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
n        time(B)         total(B)   useful-heap(B) extra-heap(B)    stacks(B)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
58        172,984           20,616           20,000           184          432
59        172,984           20,616           20,000           184          432
97.01% (20,000B) (heap allocation functions) malloc/new/new[], --alloc-fns, etc.
->48.51% (10,000B) 0x108749: main (in /home/steven/Desktop/linux-design/lab0-c/prog)
| 
->38.80% (8,000B) 0x108706: g (in /home/steven/Desktop/linux-design/lab0-c/prog)
| ->19.40% (4,000B) 0x10871C: f (in /home/steven/Desktop/linux-design/lab0-c/prog)
| | ->19.40% (4,000B) 0x108765: main (in /home/steven/Desktop/linux-design/lab0-c/prog)
| |   
| ->19.40% (4,000B) 0x10876A: main (in /home/steven/Desktop/linux-design/lab0-c/prog)
|   
->09.70% (2,000B) 0x108717: f (in /home/steven/Desktop/linux-design/lab0-c/prog)
->09.70% (2,000B) 0x108765: main (in /home/steven/Desktop/linux-design/lab0-c/prog)

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
n        time(B)         total(B)   useful-heap(B) extra-heap(B)    stacks(B)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
60        175,352           18,568           18,000           152          416
61        177,704           16,536           16,000           120          416
62        180,056           14,504           14,000            88          416
63        182,408           12,472           12,000            56          416
64        184,760           10,440           10,000            24          416
65        187,048           10,472           10,000            24          448
66        189,408           11,488           10,000            24        1,464
67        191,696           10,528           10,000            24          504
68        193,984           10,464           10,000            24          440
69        196,296           10,472           10,000            24          448
95.49% (10,000B) (heap allocation functions) malloc/new/new[], --alloc-fns, etc.
->76.39% (8,000B) 0x108706: g (in /home/steven/Desktop/linux-design/lab0-c/prog)
| ->38.20% (4,000B) 0x10871C: f (in /home/steven/Desktop/linux-design/lab0-c/prog)
| | ->38.20% (4,000B) 0x108765: main (in /home/steven/Desktop/linux-design/lab0-c/prog)
| |   
| ->38.20% (4,000B) 0x10876A: main (in /home/steven/Desktop/linux-design/lab0-c/prog)
|   
->19.10% (2,000B) 0x108717: f (in /home/steven/Desktop/linux-design/lab0-c/prog)
| ->19.10% (2,000B) 0x108765: main (in /home/steven/Desktop/linux-design/lab0-c/prog)
|   
->00.00% (0B) in 1+ places, all below ms_print's threshold (01.00%)

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
n        time(B)         total(B)   useful-heap(B) extra-heap(B)    stacks(B)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
70        198,632           10,536           10,000            24          512
71        200,936           10,472           10,000            24          448
72        203,272           10,536           10,000            24          512
```

Comment: Which tool versions are you using?

Comment: ```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kubuntu-ppa/backports 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install massif-visualizer
```
these are command how I install

Comment: my version is 0.0.7